# How do I subtract a certain number of minutes from a `DateTime` value?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In the following code, instead of current system time, I want to subtract 5 minutes as integer I from `datetime.now().tostring()`. So the warning can be played 5 minutes before the system time matches the time in labeltext1.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label_time1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    mplayer = new SoundPlayer();
    mplayer.SoundLocation = (@"c:\users\woolsvalley\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication17\WindowsFormsApplication17\Alarm.wav");
    if ((DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") == ((textBox_ordertostart.Text))))
    {
        mplayer.Play();
        pbuilder.ClearContent();

        pbuilder.AppendText("Order time for" + "" + comboBox_suburb.SelectedValue + "Start in" + 5 + "minutes");
        txt2speech.Speak(pbuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is a question about subtracting from a datetime? Please focus on that and drop out anything relating to "text to speech"

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-i)`

Comment: Using a timer to let things happen at a predetermined moment is a bad practice. You're also initializing the SoundPlayer even if it isn't going to be used.

Comment: SoundPlayer is used because there is a warning alarm and and a warning announcement. I tried to match the time in textbox_ordertostart with system.datetime.now.tostring() but i couldn't find an event which trigger the check for it.                                                                                              
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i) works but  
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-i) doesn't ... that what i am asking... thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can subtract `TimeSpan` from `DateTime`, as below:

```
DateTime fiveMinutesAgo = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0,5,0);
```

Comment: An alternative is `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)` which some might find easier to read

Comment: when i do DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5) it works but when i use DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5) it doesn't and thats the problem...

Comment: GWLlosa the timespan throwing exception : The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.